# Conversion from class member function to C-like function pointer

Tags: c++, c, curl

I am writing a C++ wrapper around cURL library for out HTTP requests.

I would like to use dedicated classes member function for cURL callbacks (cURL requires the client to provide read and write callback functions for reading and writing uploaded/downloaded content). Since cURL lib is written in C, these callbacks must be provided in the form of C functions, with following signatures:

```
size_t read_callback(char *buffer, size_t size, size_t nitems, void *userdata);
size_t write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata);
```

where `userdata` is a pointer to data saved by the user with a dedicated API.

In the pre-existing software, there were used C++ static functions as cURL callback, with the userdata equal to the `this` pointer of the object actually handling the read/write.

As said previously, I would like to pass directly to cURL a member function of a given class, using something like `std::bind` or `std::mem_fn`, but the result of these templates cannot be assigned to a C function pointer, as required in my case. Is there an elegant solution to this issue?

Comment: The common way is what you said: use a static member function. What is the problem with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i would like to pass directly to cURL a member function of a given class, using something like std::bind or std::mem_fn, but the result of these templates cannot be assigned to a C function pointer, as required in my case. Is there an elegant solution to this issue?

The solution you already have, using a static function (or a free function), is the only option.